# VIM problem: black lines when creating new line

Tags: vim, colors, background, newline

I'm using vim editor in virtualbox with vagrant, on *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*.
A few days ago, windows updated and since every time I insert a new line into vim (<kbd>Insert</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> ), it creates the new line with **black background** and the pointer shows the original color.
I've tryed with
`:set background=dark` and `:set background=light` but no good response.

Here are some pictures. It would be amazing if you can help me! Thanks in advance!

[Every black line is an enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zisWl.png)

[other example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c9UF.png)

Comment: Looks like you're using Windows Terminal... If so, does this answer address your problem? https://superuser.com/a/1527581/879179

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone.
Try to add `let &t_ut=''` to .vimrc

Comment: May you try to further comment your solution?

Answer (score -1):

Delete the current .vimrc and download a fresh .vimrc.

Comment: "Download a fresh .vimrc"? Download from where? What should it contain?